# Rspec + Capybara: Validating select options using xpath

Tags: xpath, rspec, capybara

I have an HTML document (there is a DIV with an ID of "countries" that wraps this code below), and in that I need to -

1. Validate the options in the select. I tried this but this is not valid.

   > expect(page).to have_xpath(('//*[@id="countries"]//select')[1],
   >   :options => ['US CAN GER POL'])
2. Validate that the second select is disabled
3. Validate that CAN is disabled in the first select
4. Validate that POL is selected in the first select
5. Change the selected option to GER in the first select

     ```
     <li>
       <fieldset>
         <select>
           <option value="US">USA</option>
           <option value="CAN" disabled>Canada</option>
           <option value="GER">Germany</option>
           <option value="POL" selected>Poland</option>
         </select>
       <fieldset>
     <li>
     <li>
       <fieldset>
         <select disabled>
           <option value="US">USA</option>
           <option value="CAN">Canada</option>
           <option value="GER">Germany</option>
           <option value="POL">Poland</option>
         </select>
       <fieldset>
     <li>
     ```

I appreciate any help that you can provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word of warning, I personally still use the `should` syntax for rspec, and I also use css selectors versus xpath.  I simply find them easier to read.

(1) Because you have two dropdowns without any specific IDs or class names identifying one from the other, I would use `all` to restrict the context of your expectations

`all('#countries select')[0].should have_text('USA Canada Germany Poland')`

(2) Same concept as above, restrict the scope.  Second fieldset should contain a disabled dropdown.

`all('#countries fieldset')[1].should have_css('select[disabled]')`

(3) `all('#countries select')[0].should have_css('option[disabled]', :text => 'Canada')`

(4) Same answer as #3 but with different attribute and text

(5) `all('#countries select')[0].find('option', :text => 'Germany').click`

Comment: You are Godsend Phil! Thank you, I have breaking my head for hours with this stuff.

Comment: For your given example this is a wonderful answer, if however you had any kind of identifiers on the selects (id, name, label) etc - then capybara provides the have_select matcher and find(:select, ...) finder which support options for most of what you want in more semantic terms.

Comment: @TomWalpole - In my form I dynamically add rows that have random generated names and ids, so I could not use them in my tests. As a result, this approach works better for me.